# when i filter than show the serial no random but i want serial no in filtered result in a sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery

i also want my filter is on button click in Cheque no filter it is only filter on button click but when i filter by Cheque date it is auto filter without click on button

Comment: how about sort the filtered result ?

Comment: also can you put some sample input or output for your problem ?

Comment: hey plz check my code below i write this as a answer what am doing wrong hear

Comment: Please update your question with you updated code.

Comment: And also please provide minimal code. that's too much of information